# How do i iterate over JSON data in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

**What i'm trying to do:**
Have some practice with fetching data in react, and i used a covid19 api with number of cases etc...

Here's the code :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const Home = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const result = await axios("api_here",);
        setData([result.data]);
    };
    fetchData();
}, [])
console.log(data);//i have a screen-shot below for the output
return (
    <ul>
        {data.map((items, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{JSON.stringify(items)}</li>
            //<li key={index}>{items}</li> This doesn't work
        ))}
    </ul>
 )} export default Home;
```

The problem is that the data is an array of 1 element, image here:
[image]

And data.map is iterating only on json[0] but i need to iterate over every country from the json.

I tried doing something like :

```
setData([result.data][0])
//or
data[0].map......
```

But doesn't work

A picture with the json data:
[image]

Comment: use `setData(result.data);` instead of `setData([result.data]);`

Comment: @ShivamJha this still doesn't fix the problem

Comment: what's the result of `console.log()` after the above suggestion?

Comment: @ShivamJha https://imgur.com/a/x558o6S

Comment: use `Object.keys(data).map()` then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is a map of key -> value so to iterate over all countries (keys).

```
<ul>
    {Object.keys(data).map((key, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{JSON.stringify(data[key])}</li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Convert the Object of Objects to Array of Objects.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const Home = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const result = await axios("api_here",);
        let res = [result.data];
        res = Object.entries(res[0]).map((e) => ( { [e[0]]: e[1] } ));
        setData(res);
    };
    fetchData();
}, [])
console.log(data);
return (
    <ul>
        {data.map((items, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{JSON.stringify(items)}</li>
            //<li key={index}>{items}</li> This doesn't work
        ))}
    </ul>
 )} export default Home;
```